# json.dump throwing “TypeError: {…} is not JSON serializable” on wtf form validation errors

Tags: python, json, flask

I would like to handle wtf form via Ajax post request in flask.

```
form = LoginForm(request.form)  
if form.validate(): 
   ..... 
   .... do something
   .....
form.errors['iserror'] = True
return json.dumps(form.errors)
```

But I get this error

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py", line 173, in default raise 
 
TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: l'A Username or E-Mail Address is required.' is not JSON serializable

Do I need to do some processing on form.errors before using in json.dumps ?

Output of form.error
{'iserror': True, 'password': [l'A Password is required.'], 'csrf_token': ['CSRF token missing'], 'username': [l'A Username or E-Mail Address is required.']}

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the form.errors string look like - maybe a dumb question, but are you sure it is json? Can you post the string above? thx.

Comment: seems "L" in front of error message for password and username is the issue. I guess it would require some processing.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the issue. problem was in my validation message. I have answered the question

Answer (score 0):

Problem was my validation message. Not sure why I had _ before the message and that was causing the issue.

```
password = PasswordField(_("Password"), validators=[
          DataRequired(message=_("A Password is required."))])
```

Works fine having after changing the form validation to

```
password = PasswordField(("Password"), validators=[
          DataRequired(message=("A Password is required."))])
```

Comment: The underscore is the most common alias for the `gettext` function of which handles [translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/). The return value of the function is not an object that the json library knows how to serialize. You can force the message to become a string with `str()` and then it will work just fine.